# How to make PHP search bar give multiple results

Tags: php, html

I made a search bar In PHP. It all works and everything Is fine. The thing that isnt working Is bringing up similar/multiple results. I have a database and two things in the database "Sword Art Online: Sword Art Online" and the other Is "Sword Art Online: Extra" If I look up sword In the search bar It will only show one. I would like it to show all matching results as well.

[This image Is what the database looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcvbd.png)

**Here Is the HTML with the PHP**

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>OPTIMA</title>
</head>
<body class="body">
<h1 class="logotext">OPTIMA</h1>
<div class="wrap">
<form method="post" action="#">
   <div class="search" method="GET">
      <input id="search" type="text" name="search"  class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search an anime." autocomplete="off">
      <button type="submit" name="submit" class="searchButton">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
     </button>
</div>
   </div>
   </form>
   <h1 class="recents">Recent Animes:</h1>

</div>
</form>
<?php
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=optimadb",'root','');

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $str = strtolower($_POST["search"]);
    $sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM information WHERE lower(title) LIKE '%$str%'");
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO:: FETCH_OBJ);
    $sth -> execute();
    if($row = $sth->fetch())
    {
        echo"
        <table class='tablepreview'>
            <tr>
                <td class='textright'>$row->title</td>
            </tr>
            <div class'thumbnail'><img src='$row->thumbnail' width='300'/></div>
        </table>";
    }
    else{
        echo "Name Does not exist";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: What does `$sth` return?

Comment: Query looks to be correct, are you sure it is only returning one result?

Comment: @Skully yeah It only returns that one result. I looked up the first word which both of them share and It only showed one

Comment: @Fresz Im not 100% sure but i think It returns the lookup string

Comment: I would assume it should return some sort of array... if it does then you need a foreach loop... can you `error_log(print_r($sth))` and let us know what is the result?

Answer (score 2):

In first, you should use prepared statement instead of string interpolation to avoid SQL injection:

```php
$sth = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM information WHERE lower(title) LIKE :title");
$sth->bindParam('title', "%$str%");
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php#example-998

In second, you must iterate over recordset and not just acces first record:

```php
$stmt->execute();
while ($record = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $record->title;
}
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#example-1040

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 main options you can do.
[fetch()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) returns the *next* row, so you can iterate over that with a while loop like Christophe suggested

```
while($row = $sth->fetch())
```

The other thing you could use is `fetchAll()`. [fetchAll()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) returns an array of all objects fetched that you can iterate over.